# Tensorflow very high loss value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, DenseFeatures
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import tensorflow.keras.optimizers as op
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('raw-img/training', batch_size=1,
                                          class_mode='categorical', subset="training")

validation_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory('raw-img/validation', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=1,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')
testing_dataset = test.flow_from_directory('raw-img/testing', target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=1,
                                           class_mode='categorical')


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3), padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    #

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same'),

    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    #
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    #
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.01),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),

])
# print the summary of the model architecture
model.summary()

rlronp = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=.8, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='min')
es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=15, verbose=1,
                                      restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=op.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100, batch_size=1, validation_data=validation_dataset,
                      callbacks=[rlronp, es])
```

5865/26179 [=====>........................] - ETA: 12:23 - loss: 34992108.0000 - accuracy: 0.1589

Hello I have train model with adam optimizer but loss rate very high I have try to change optimizer to SDG but the predict not true.

How could I change in code to get better result and low loss value.

loss value  34992108.0000

Comment: Try adding `BatchNormalization()` layers in every CNN block. The `batch_size` is 1 try changing it to 32 or 64.

Comment: Did the solution from @AdarshWase solved your problem?

Comment: @AdarshWase i have try add BatchNormalization() after Dropout and then before Dropout layer loss decrease to 2.200 . but  loss value stack on this value (2.200)

Comment: where should i add BatchNormalization() exactly ??

Comment: After the activation layer.

Comment: @AdarshWase nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same code and find the fix of this issue which you can try by doing below changes in your model definition:

1. You need to remove all the `Dropout layers` defined before of
   `Flatten()` layer in the model.
2. Also define `batch_size=128` while training the dataset.

Let us know if issue still persists. Happy Coding!